# Why are the answer options for all questions appearing in this single question?

Tags: javascript

This is a quiz in which each question has 4 answer options. I'm looping through the question one by one and trying to make it appear with its corresponding answer options, but the question is appearing with the answer options of other questions as well. What could I be missing here?

```
var questionOne = function () {
  // create container to hold questions and answer options & give it a class name
  var questionsDiv = document.createElement("div");
  questionsDiv.className = "questions-div";

  // create question stem, give it a class name, add its content, & append to questionsDiv
  var questionStem = document.createElement("h2");
  questionStem.className = "question-stem";
  questionStem.innerText = quizQuestions[currentQuestion].question;
  questionsDiv.append(questionStem);

  // create container to hold answer option buttons
  var answerOptionsDiv = document.createElement("div");

  // create footer container, give it a class name, & append to the questionsContainer
  var footerDiv = document.createElement("div");
  footerDiv.className = "footer-div";
  questionsContainer.append(footerDiv);

  // create footer text (correct/wrong), give it a class name, & append to footerDiv
  var footerTextCorrect = document.createElement("h2");
  footerTextCorrect.className = "footer-text-correct";
  footerTextCorrect.innerText = "Correct!";
  footerDiv.append(footerTextCorrect);

  var footerTextWrong = document.createElement("h2");
  footerTextWrong.className = "footer-text-wrong";
  footerTextWrong.innerText = "Wrong!";
  footerDiv.append(footerTextWrong);

  // append questionsDiv to main questions container
  questionsContainer.append(questionsDiv);

  // append answerOptionsDiv to questions container
  questionsDiv.append(answerOptionsDiv);

  // loop through the questions
  for (let i = 0; i < quizQuestions.length; i++) {
    console.log(quizQuestions[currentQuestion].question);

    for (let j = 1; j <= 4; j++) {
      console.log(`${j}. ${quizQuestions[currentQuestion].options[`${j}`]}`);

      // create buttons for answer options and add their content
      var optionBtnOne = document.createElement("button");
      optionBtnOne.innerText = `${j}. ${
        quizQuestions[currentQuestion].options[`${j}`]
      }`;
      // append button to answerOptionsDiv
      answerOptionsDiv.append(optionBtnOne);
      optionBtnOne.addEventListener("click", selectAnswer);
      optionBtnOne.setAttribute(
        "id",
        `${quizQuestions[currentQuestion].options[`${j}`]}`
      );
    }
    currentQuestion++;
  }
};
```

Comment: This function is only supposed to display question 1, but you're looping through the entire `quizQuestions` array. Shouldn't you just use `quizQuestions[0]`? And the `questionTwo()` function should use `quizQuestions[1]`, and so on. You could also just have a single function that takes the index as a parameter, so you don't have to duplicate all the code.

Comment: Please note that with JavaScript, people can see the answer to your quiz questions if it isn't properly [obfuscated](https://obfuscator.io/).

Comment: @Barmar: The question is displaying fine (only question 1). It's the answer choices that appearing incorrectly. Could you elaborate on what you meant please?

Comment: I'm talking about this loop: `for (let i = 0; i < quizQuestions.length; i++)`. But you never use `quizQuestions[i]`, so now I don't understand the reason for the loop.

Comment: You're also incrementing `currentQuestion` in that loop. That's why you're getting the answers to all the questions.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have the loop that iterates through the `quizQuestions` array. This function should just process `quizQuestions[currentQuestion]`. The `currentQuestion` index should be incremented when the user goes to the next question, not in this function.

```js
var questionOne = function() {
  // create container to hold questions and answer options & give it a class name
  var questionsDiv = document.createElement("div");
  questionsDiv.className = "questions-div";

  // create question stem, give it a class name, add its content, & append to questionsDiv
  var questionStem = document.createElement("h2");
  questionStem.className = "question-stem";
  questionStem.innerText = quizQuestions[currentQuestion].question;
  questionsDiv.append(questionStem);

  // create container to hold answer option buttons
  var answerOptionsDiv = document.createElement("div");

  // create footer container, give it a class name, & append to the questionsContainer
  var footerDiv = document.createElement("div");
  footerDiv.className = "footer-div";
  questionsContainer.append(footerDiv);

  // create footer text (correct/wrong), give it a class name, & append to footerDiv
  var footerTextCorrect = document.createElement("h2");
  footerTextCorrect.className = "footer-text-correct";
  footerTextCorrect.innerText = "Correct!";
  footerDiv.append(footerTextCorrect);

  var footerTextWrong = document.createElement("h2");
  footerTextWrong.className = "footer-text-wrong";
  footerTextWrong.innerText = "Wrong!";
  footerDiv.append(footerTextWrong);

  // append questionsDiv to main questions container
  questionsContainer.append(questionsDiv);

  // append answerOptionsDiv to questions container
  questionsDiv.append(answerOptionsDiv);
  console.log(quizQuestions[currentQuestion].question);

  for (let j = 1; j <= 4; j++) {
    console.log(`${j}. ${quizQuestions[currentQuestion].options[`${j}`]}`);

    // create buttons for answer options and add their content
    var optionBtnOne = document.createElement("button");
    optionBtnOne.innerText = `${j}. ${
        quizQuestions[currentQuestion].options[`${j}`]
      }`;
    // append button to answerOptionsDiv
    answerOptionsDiv.append(optionBtnOne);
    optionBtnOne.addEventListener("click", selectAnswer);
    optionBtnOne.setAttribute(
      "id",
      `${quizQuestions[currentQuestion].options[`${j}`]}`
    );
  }
};
```

Comment: Thai was really useful. Thanks for helping me understand where the logic went wrong!